# Angular FullCalendar events not rendering properly

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement FullCalendar in my Angular app and everything was working before I added some events to timeGrid. The problem is that events are rendering under the whole grid which is unacceptable. I've searched for solutions but didn't find anything. Changing versions of Angular or FullCalendar didnt' help.

[image]

I've found the same problem in some app on stackblitz but couldn't solve it anyway.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The problem is only when events have specified start time and calendar is set to timeGrid. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I've managed to find a solution. The problem was that css files weren't imported by default - I've read about it in docs but importing it didn't work for me. Now I've tried to import this directly to css file and it worked!

`@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';`

Hope this may help someone.

Comment: You should add your findings to the Answers section below (instead of just a comment). That way 1) people can upvote your answer if they find it useful, 2) your question and answer will show up more in searches (because questions with answers are ranked more highly). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution. The problem was that css files weren't imported by default - I've read about it in docs but importing it in html didn't work. Now I've tried to import this directly to css file and it worked!

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
```

Hope this may help someone.